# Why is mysql asking for password after default installation as root

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-20.04

I see this when I ssh to my Ubuntu server:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-1018-aws x86_64)
```

After installing mysql, I try to login to the mysql server but for some reason it asks me for a password that I do not have. So, I ran the following commands to uninstall mysql and reinstall.

Uninstall

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*
sudo apt-get purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get remove dbconfig-mysql
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

The I used [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-20-04) link as guide to install mysql, and the commands went as follows:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mysql-server
sudo systemctl start mysql.service
```

When I run:

```bash
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

The prompt asks me to “Enter password for the user root”. Where do I find this password?

The idea of the command is to set the password.

How can I install mysql in this server to then be able to manage my databases?